# On the laplacian of connected, undirected, multigraphs without loops

Tags: ct.category-theory, graph-theory, lattices, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a connected, undirected multigraph, without loops. 
Let $L_G = D_G - A_G$, 
where $D_G= diag (val (v_1), \ldots , val (v_n) )$ where $n$ is the no. of vertices of $G$ and $val (v_i)$ denotes the valence (i.e. degree ) of $v_i$, 
and where $A_G$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$, i.e. the $ij$-th entry of $A_G$  is $1$ if vertices $v_i, v_j$ are adjacent the entry is $0$ otherwise. That is, $L_G$ is the Laplacian matrix of $G$.

Then let $L(G)$ denote the subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$ generated by the columns of $L_G$, let us call it the Laplacian lattice of the graph $G$. So given a graph, we can naturally associate a group with it.

Now given  two connected, undirected multigraphs without loops $G,H$;

> Can we define a suitable subset $Mor (G,H)$ of the set of all graph homomorphisms between the graphs such that the collection of all connected, undirected graphs, without loops, as objects along with the suitable set of morphisms, form a category such that the Laplacian group of the graphs is a functorial construction?

(the target space being the category of abelian groups and group homomorphisms
 ... of course given a morphism between graphs as in the category, we will need to define a suitable morphism between the Laplacian groups of the two graphs ... that's part of the problem too ... and I would be happy if we can even get a contravariant functor ) ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the topic of David Treumann's honors thesis ["Functoriality of critical groups"](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~reiner/HonorsTheses/Treumann_thesis.pdf).  There is also some discussion with more references in the introduction of ["Critical groups of covering, voltage, and signed graphs"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.2977) by Reiner and Tseng:

> [...] there is some literature relating critical groups for different graphs in a functorial fashion, having roots in an early paper$^1$
>   of Berman [8], work of Lorenzini [13], and unpublished work of Treumann[16]; see [6, 7] for some notable applications of this functoriality; the theory is reviewed in Section 2.2 below.
>   More recently, the role of critical groups in the analogy between graphs and algebraic curves, discussed originally by Bacher, de la Harpe and Nagnibeda [2] (see also Biggs [9]) has been extended further to
>   chip-firing or sandpile groups of metric graphs and the theory of tropical geometry, where some of these notions of functoriality appear also in work of Urakawa [18] and Baker and Norine [4, 5] under the name of
>   harmonic morphisms; for a recent survey and references, see Perkinson et al [15].